# Does xcode compile commented out lines?

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction, build, io

Simple question, will anything commented out be left out by the compiler?

Anything with // or /*

I believe so, but want to double check.

Comment: If any modern compiler were to ship with this as a feature, not only would it be laughed out of the field, but it would probably be magnetically erased in anger.  Comments are comments, not code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, never. XCode does not compile commented line.